# Problems with the language after update

Tags: language

good Morning, 
I performed the update from ver. 1.8.1.0 to 1.9 of my website ([Gadget Personalizzati e Articoli Promozionali bestpromotion.it](http://bestpromotion.it)
But now everything is in English instead of Italian even if wherever is specified the Italian

Answer (score 1):

- Check that the right locale is defined in backend (check that you are in the right storeview)
- check that all translations files exist in `app/locale/`
- be sure, that your translation files are for the right magento version, because magento changes the original strings from version to version :-(